# Table fixed Header: set width

Tags: css, html-table

I have this table [this table](http://develop.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/table.html) and as you can see I have a "fixed header"

HTML:

```
<table>
<div class="table-head">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Haus/ Objekt-Nr.</th>
<th>Zimmer</th>
<th>Stockwerk</th>
<th>Netto-MZ</th>
<th>Brutto-MZ</th>
<th>PDF</th>
</tr>   
</thead>
</div> 
</table>
```

How can I set the same space that I'm using in the table below between `th` elements in the fixed header?

Is possible to make it works also on mobile?

Comment: Do you have separate tables for both the header and the body of the table?

Comment: You can't officially have a div within table tags..

Comment: Try this demo http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx